# UserForm.Show within a prior Initial User form causes blank grey un-closeable workbook to open

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the excerpt of code where the "error(more like an unwanted occurrence)" happens. My code is running in a userform (not userform1) after a command button click. The initial form shows on workbook open. The second userform - UserForm1 in the code below - is a check box that I want to present to the user upon my IF condition. When the program gets there, it opens the UserForm1, but also opens a blank grey excel workbook. The workbook cannot be closed until I close the Userformm1 interface.

Note: the second msgbox does not display until AFTER I close the userform.
I tried searching for this problem, but couldn't find the issue in regards to UserForm stuff. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim wbName As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim counter As Integer
Dim EstNumAttempt As Boolean
EstNumAttemp = False

counter = 0

Dim ThisNum As String
Dim EstNum As String
Dim CopyFromBook As Workbook
Dim CopyToWbk As Workbook
Dim ShToCopy As Worksheet


Set CopyToWbk = ThisWorkbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisUserPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

userDataPath = ThisUserPath & "\SBNBidDataSet01112018.xlsx"

Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String


StartDate = TextBox1.Value
EndDate = TextBox2.Value
EstNum = TextBox3.Value



Set wb = Workbooks.Open(userDataPath)



Set CopyFromWbk = wb

WSCount = wb.Worksheets.Count




If EstNum <> "" Then

EstNumAttempt = True

For X = 1 To WSCount


Set ws = wb.Sheets(X)
ThisNum = ws.Cells(2, 2)

If ThisNum = EstNum Then

 counter = counter + 1
 Set ShToCopy = CopyFromWbk.Worksheets(X)
 ShToCopy.Copy After:=CopyToWbk.Sheets(CopyToWbk.Sheets.Count)

End If

Next X

If counter = 0 Then

   MsgBox " That's probably not a valid EST# in SmartBidNet"

End If

End If


If IsDate(StartDate) = True And IsDate(EndDate) = True And EstNumAttempt = False Then
MsgBox "h"
wb.Application.Visible = False
UserForm1.Show
wb.Application.Visible = True

MsgBox "h"
'BLANK GREY SHEET HERE

For X = 100 To 101

    Set ws = wb.Sheets(X)

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    'future code

Next X

End If

wb.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' from before also!


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there code behind `UserForm1`, like, a `Private Sub UserForm_Activate` handler? The workbook can't be closed because the form is modal - *nothing* can be done outside the form until it's closed, that's what *modal* dialogs do.

Comment: @Mat'sMug hello again! There is currently no code behind userForm1 - i tried putting some screen updating stuff in there but nothing works.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I know that the form is modal - i just don't know why when it gets to the UserForm1.show line it then also shows a new blank grey workbook.

Comment: Well, showing a form doesn't automagically open a workbook - you have code *somewhere* that's doing it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I added the whole code - I don't think I'm opening it anywhere else. If i remove the UserForm1.show and leave it alone my initial form via the command button 1 works fine.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I can solve my issue using a nasty use of application.visible, but id really like to find out why that blank grey workbook appears upon userform1.show. Can this be some weird system thing and not a code issue?

Comment: I would suggest leaving the app visible and not toggle it.  Where you put the worksheet showing up in code and where you describe it in your description are not the same.  In code you would have to close msgbox, form, msgbox for it to appear as stated.  In description it shows up when the form shows up.  Could be your workbook.Close and screenupdating.  in addition you make two references to the same workbook and only close one, there is some interchangeability used as well :Set wb = Workbooks.Open(userDataPath)



Set CopyFromWbk = wb
wb.Close

Comment: Do you hide the form?  do you unload it?  How do you terminate your userforms after showing them?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sorry - grey sheet is right after the .show line. Also tried doing away with the copyfromwkbk reference cause in my case right now the If EstNum <> ""  doesn't fire off so i don't need it temporarily. Tried application updating false and true alllll over. Cant get the blank workbook to stop appearing.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code I just rely on the user to close the first userform when they are done - since it only works via commandbutton i reinitialize all variable on the click

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code - nothing for the UserForm1 because I just got to it and saw that this blank workbook was appearing right after userform.show

Comment: sounds more like a windows (making an assumption here) residue as the screen isn't refreshed. I tested the meat of that code and it does not provide a legacy grey box (and my userform is a grey box).  This is more in Matt's league than mine, when does the grey box go away?  How do you get rid of it currently?  You say its a grey workbook . . . problem could be in tour worksheet code up above this section . . . . 
  https://superuser.com/questions/852251/how-to-clear-screen-artifacts-without-rebooting-windows-multiple-versions

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code Its not a gray box. Its literally a new workbook shell htat opens up and where the cells are its just all grey. I don't know if its a residue cause restarting should've fixed it temporarily.  Right now the first form is on workbook open. When that runs on a button click it results in opening up this UserForm1 so the user can make some secondary selections. Right after UserForm1.show executes - the grey workbook appears. The grey workbook will close when I close the UserForm1 with X. no Unload or hide or anything like that.

Comment: I am not sure its a new workbook. See this link:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2790615/parts-of-excel-turn-white-or-gray-when-you-run-vba-code-in-excel-2013 ,, I just made a pile of userforms, one opening another and also inline with the button code, they do not artifact on the screen, when I close the second msgbox I might get a flicker of one, but then its gone with the added workbook.

Comment: tested further code below, its nonsensical, but still no grey workbook / worksheet.  It does however prompt me to save the new workbook after I add those sheets when it gets to close, that's about it.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code - I fixed it by adding wb.windows(1).visible = false before my IF statement that checks for isDate. Now the workbook that was opening I was able to verify was the wb that I load from userDataPath in the earlier portion of the code. Since screen updating was false - it came up as just grey, but the wb workbook still opened none the less. The weird part though is why does it only open visibly upon the UserForm1.Show call and not ever through my original user form that the code is in? Either way - thank you very much for the time and effort!

Comment: glad you found it! showing and hiding workbooks and sheets, co-mingled with forms can be strange.  After thorough testing of the code (so you don't get hung with no updating) I might shut things off once at the top of a sub and then back on upon exit.  I don't do much of that, just hide workbooks opening, processing, and closing that is about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION, I tested a piece of your code and here is my feedback below.

I ran just this code in a workbook named testbook.xslm and I created a form (myForm that is just a grey layout, nothing on it):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim anotherbook As Workbook
Dim anotherbook2 As Workbook
Dim anotherbook3 As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set anotherbook = wb
Set anotherbook2 = wb
Set anotherbook3 = wb


MsgBox "h"
wb.Application.Visible = False
myForm.Show
wb.Application.Visible = True

MsgBox "h"

wb.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' from before also!
End Sub
```

From the user standpoint:

1) testbook opens

2) click the button -> book# opens on top of testbook

3) msgbox "h" pops up

4) x out of msgbox "h" -> **Both workbooks disappear** (testbook and book1)

5) my grey user form pops up (its empty)

6) x out of userform

7) testbook shows again on top of the new book created which is behind it

8) msgbox "h" #2 pops up

9) x out of msgbox

10) the book# behind testbook disappears

That's it.  No grey box residue.  How are you closing the userforms (the first one and the second one)?  obviously I used the terminate with the x.  I did not add any code.  So how are you closing your form with no code?

Adding the same behavior occurs if I make multiple workbook references to wb.
So this code area is not your problem . . . .

Second test, still no problems, adding worksheets, running through the number of worksheets, copying them to the testbook.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim anotherbook As Workbook
Dim anotherbook2 As Workbook
Dim anotherbook3 As Workbook
Dim X As Double
Dim lastrow As Double
Dim thisNum As String


Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set anotherbook = wb
Set anotherbook2 = wb
Set anotherbook3 = wb
Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

wb.Worksheets.Add
wb.Worksheets.Add
wb.Worksheets.Add
wb.Worksheets.Add
wb.Worksheets.Add
wb.Worksheets.Add

myForm2.Show

MsgBox "h"
wb.Application.Visible = False
myForm.Show
wb.Application.Visible = True

MsgBox "h"

For X = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count


    Set ws = wb.Sheets(X)
    thisNum = ws.Cells(2, 2)

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Copy After:=wb2.Worksheets(wb2.Worksheets.Count)

    'future code

Next X

wb.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' from before also!
End Sub
```

Perhaps you have a lot of data being acted upon.  Clear the clipboard after the paste?  With:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Digging - WWC